# What's the correct way to imply that a course is not taken online?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, terminology

I'd like to know how I should write on my CV that some courses I've taken were taken online (i.e. on websites, through videos and such) while others were actually taken on an institute/school etc.

For example:

- Online Education

  - Foo (at example.com)
  - Bar (at somesite.com)
- (place your suggestion here) education

  - Baz
  - Quux

There's a word in Portuguese which is sometimes used to convey that meaning: *presencial*. I think it *would* be possible to use the English word *presential* with the same meaning, but somehow it doesn't sound so natural.

Could anybody present some possibilities? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If there is a commonly used and readily understood term that unambiguously defines that you studied at a bricks-and-mortar classroom, something like as 'Classroom Instruction', you could use it. Else it is essential that you redraft in an unambiguous way. After all, you would not expect the reader to run and get a dictionary in the middle of reading the CV, right? :)

Comment: If you can revise this question and post it on writersSE, I might want to make a simple suggestion. That would be out of scope on ELU, though.

Comment: *Attended* Baz, [years]. Attended Quux, [years]. (those would be their own headings, only Online Ed would have bullet points, or have each of them postfaced with *online*.) .... *attend* : "be present at"

Comment: I would distinguish between 'On-line, Virtual', 'On-line, Live', and 'In Person, Live'. Note the (old-fashioned, British approach) to hyphenating the compound adjective. On a practical note, it would be entirely possible to be registered at an educational institution, and not attend lectures given live, but listen to recordings made available to students, and then sit the exams which could be via computer ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two terms that can be used are:

- In residence (or "resident")
- Face-to-face

The term face-to-face is often used in educational literature (e.g., see [this Google result](http://www.google.com/search?rls=en&q=online%20vs%20face%20to%20face&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)).

Comment: @XavierVidalHernández: I've included a link with over 200 million references. Moreover, EL&U has a long history of recognizing concise answers that answer the question, like [this answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44037/what-does-ctee-mean/44038#44038) and [this answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/61732/winter-wintry-summer-summery-spring-autumn/61733#61733), for example. By downvoting based on brevity, you are setting a bad precedent. As per the FAQ, misinformation should be voted down, not succinctness.

Comment: @tchrist: At our school, we differentiate between on-site and in-residence as follows: when the instructor travels to another location, that's *on-site* training; when the students travel to our school, that's *in-residence* training – although I'm not prepared to say that those are universally recongnized distinctions. Getting back to the O.P.'s question, the term "on campus" might be useful, too.

Comment: @XavierVidalHernández: I didn't ask you to "revert your choice," I merely pointed out that you have offered a faulty reason for downvoting. I could care less if you reverse your downvote on my answer, but, if you keep downvoting other answers for that reason, then your reputation on this site will sink even lower than it already has. I was trying to help you.

Comment: What about *on-premises* ? or is it *in-premises* or *on-premise* ?

Comment: @Felipe Almeida ... sorry, but on-premises or in-premises do not make sense in English language!

Comment: @FelipeAlmeida: For the purposes of your outline, _On-premises education_ could work, as a counterpart for _Online education_. I'd be more inclined to use _On campus_ if the classes were taken on a college campus, but if they were taken at a corporate learning center, then either _On-premises_ or _In residence_ could work.

Comment: @J.R. could I ask you to update your answer with all alternatives so I can tick you up (not sure about the usage of this last expression =))

Comment: @XavierVidalHernández: _"on-premises or in-premises do not make sense in English language!"_ Oh, [really](http://www.lumesse.com/what-we-do/technology-choices/hosted-on-premises)? What makes you say [that](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q="classes+held+on+premises")?

Comment: Yeah. I've definitely heard/read at least **one** of the alternatives I've given. How can someone offer such an unwavering answer without researching at least a little bit first?

Comment: @FelipeAlmeida: Out of all the options discussed so far, I'd be  inclined to stick with "in residence" or "face-to-face" (especially as an answer to the question in your question's title), so I'd prefer to leave my answer in its original form.  "On campus" and "on-premises" are two alternatives that wouldn't strike me as erroneous, though, so don't be afraid of going with one of those, if you think one of them would be a better fit for your particular application.

Comment: @tchrist I like *on-site* too but I think the context I'm using it in would perhaps cause confusion because people could mistake it for *on a website*. Other than that I really like *on-site*.

Comment: “In residence” means “In my home”, right?  And “face-to-face” means your web-cam and the instructor's are pointed at your faces?  And “on-premises” and “in-premises” mean that the computer I'm using for the online instruction is on my own premises, instead of someone else's?  In short, it looks like all those options work well to designate at-home online instruction, but the question asks (I think) about how to designate classes taken in the same room with the instructor, that is to say, it asks about classroom instruction.

Comment: @jwpat7: The term "face-to-face instruction" is a regularly-used term in educational journals, and it does not mean webcams pointed at the face, it means students in the classroom. Your point is well-taken – those unfamiliar with a certain terminology can misread certain words if they don't have the right background, so you need to know your audience. I won't argue that "classroom instruction" isn't yet another word that the O.P. could use, but I will maintain that "resident courses" and "face-to-face instruction" are commonly used terms in the education field to refer to "non-online courses."

Answer (score 1):

The term [***traditional classroom***](http://www.westga.edu/~distance/ojdla/winter24/omalley24.html) or *traditional classroom setting* is used in scholarly writing to refer to that mode of content delivery.  Other modes of delivery are the *online* setting and the *hybrid* setting.

Answer (score 0):

"In-person" is the first thing that comes to my mind.